# One-to-one Proof

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If f is a differentiable, one-to-one function and $f(a) = b$, then

$(f^{-1})'(b)=\frac{1}{f'(a)}$

Obtain (with proof) similar equations for $(f^{-1})''(b)$, $(f^{-1})'''(b)$, in terms of $f'(a)$, $f''(a)$, $f'''(a)$.

How would I obtain these similar equations?

Comment: Did you mean $=\frac1{f'(a)}$?

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't know how to format that correctly

Comment: You can show that a one-to-one function in $\mathbb R$ implies that it is either strictly decreasing or strictly increasing. Use that fact to prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous in $b$. Finally, you use the definition of derivative.

Comment: could you show me a few steps?

Comment: give me a couple of minutes then

Comment: @EA304GT You better hurry.

Comment: @NormalHuman  I know I shouldn't be doing somebody's else homework.

Comment: anyone care to show me a few steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose we already know the facts that

> A continuous 1-1 function is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing

and

> If $f$ is a continuous 1-1 functions, so it is $f^{-1}$

We also need the hypothesis that $f'(a)$ exists and it is not 0.

By definition of derivative we have that

$$(f^{-1})'(b)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f^{-1}(b+h)-f^{-1}(b)}h$$

Due to continuity of $f^{-1}$, for a small enough $h$ there is a small enough $k_h$ such that $f(a+k_h)=y+h$ where $k_h\rightarrow0$ as $h\rightarrow0$. So we have

$$(f^{-1})'(b)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{a-k_h-a}{f(a+k_h)-f(a)}=\frac1{\lim_{k_h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+k_h)-f(a)}{k_h}}=\frac1{f'(a)}$$

Comment: Ok but how would I show this for (f^-1)''(b) and (f^-1)'''(b) ?

Comment: Now that you know that $f^{-1}$ is derivable when $f'(a)\neq0$, you can use chain rule.

Comment: how would I use the chain rule in this question?

Comment: What does chain rule say?

Comment: (f o g)'(x)= f'(g(x))g'(x). How would I use this rule in this question though.

Comment: $(f^{-1})''(b) = (1/f'(a))'$

Comment: So essentially, I just have to find the first and second derivative of the fraction?

Comment: Yes. Just a tip: It would be easier if you keep in mind that $a$ and $b$ are related by rewriting $(f^{-1})'(a) = 1/f'(f^{-1}(a))$